# Differentiability at a point when you actually want in a neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on an open interval $I$ containing $c$. If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, and $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ are sequences in $I$ such that $x_{n}<c<y_{n}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(y_{n}-x_{n})=0$, then prove that

$ \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{f(y_{n})-f(x_{n})}{y_{n}-x_{n}}=f'(c).$

If we were given that $f$ was differentiable in a neighborhood about $c$ the problem is trivial by the mean value theorem. So without that I don't know how to proceed with this problem. And I don't think there is any way to show that $f$ is analytic at $c$.

Comment: Why is it trivial if $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood? You seem to be further assuming continuity of the derivative. Think for example of the continuous extension of $x^2\sin(1/x)$, and of its derivative at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(c)$ exists, 
$$f(y_n)-f(c)=(y_n-c)f'(c)+g(y_n)(y_n-c),$$
where $\lim_{y_n\to c}g(y_n)=0$. 
Similarly,
$$f(x_n)-f(c)=(x_n-c)f'(c)+h(x_n)(x_n-c).$$ 
where $\lim_{x_n\to 0} h(x_n)=0$. 
Subtract. We get 
$$f(y_n)-f(x_n)=(y_n-x_n)f'(c)+g(y_n)(y_n-c)+h(x_n)(c-x_n).$$
Divide by $y_n-x_n$. We get
$$\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}=f'(c)+g(y_n)\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}+h(x_n)\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}.$$
Finally, let $x_n$ and $y_n$ approach $c$.

The ratios $\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}$ and
$\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}$  are positive and less  than $1$. (This is the crucial part of the argument.)

It follows that the error term $g(y_n)\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}+h(x_n)\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rewrite the numerator as $\big(f(y_n)-f(c)\big)+\big(f(c)-f(x_n)\big)$.